# How can I remove HTML tag from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have JSON file like

```
[{"description":"<p> example...</p> </br> <p>paragraph... </p> <div id="test" class="test2" style="left: -10000px; top: 10px; position:absolute;"> <p>paragraph... </p> "}]
```

So how can I remove the HTML tage such as `<p> </p>` `</br>` to display in ionic-framework

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/KxwgffjLoi56OR593YFg?p=preview check this

Comment: One more thing I set JSON into a local url like 

http://103.245.167.48/~icenter/video/api.php

So how can I apply to show it. Can you?

Comment: HTML tag contain on  `description field`

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use an HTML parser oriented solution to filter out the tags, here's a simple regex for it.

```
var noHTML =  OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

[Here is the working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iunCqIcA8UwaWYIesTCd)

Comment: One more thing I set JSON into a local url like 

http://103.245.167.48/~icenter/video/api.php  

So how can I apply to show it. Can you?

Comment: HTML tag contain on `description field `